# Sound not playing fully?

Tags: python, pyglet

The problem is when i play a sound it stops/cuts before finishing playing. (sound being under 1 second)

```
import pyglet
#from time import sleep

window = pyglet.window.Window()

# i use this for my code.
#pyglet.resource.path = ['/resources']
#pyglet.resource.reindex()
#bullet_sound = pyglet.resource.media("bullet.wav", streaming=False)
                                            ## streaming fix's an error message

bullet_sound = pyglet.media.load("/resources/bullet.wav", streaming=False)

@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    # sound only plays for a millisecond 
    bullet_sound.play()

    # this lets the sound complete
    #sleep(1)

    # also tried this with 'update()'
    #player.queue(bullet_sound)

#def update(dt):
#    player.play()
#pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1/120.0)

pyglet.app.run()
```

I can't seem to find anything about this when google searching. Sleeping makes the sound finish, so i suppose it has something to do with it dropping the sound prematurely. But how to i get it not to do so?

I even tried using the player, putting it in an update function and queuing it from the event, but that din't change anything.

Comment: Do you really want to make that event take that much time, or do you simply want app.run() to not return until the audio queue is empty?

Comment: I want to play the sound every time the player click's the button and just over ride the other sound if it has to, thought while testing i had some other issues, when i played the sound it played fully, and sounded fine, but after 2 - 5 times, it generates a segmentation fault.(On python 3) Python 2 generates a too large error.  But again after pressing a few times.

Comment: I need to test more later because im all out of time, but i think they're pyglet on linux mint, issues. The segmentation fault at less, no idea how to deal with the 'too large'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segmentation faults, sound cutting, too large exceptions, sound related issues on linux mint might be caused by Linux/PulseAudio, the fix is using OpanAL, installing(might be pre-installed on mint) then adding a line to use it after importing pyglet:

```
pyglet.options['audio'] = ('openal', 'silent')
```